# How to know which methods are associated with an event?

Tags: unity, events

In Unity `events` are used as enhanced `delegates`.
This is extremely helpful in developing clean concise event management scripts.

However, when debugging said scripts and complex arrangements, is there a way I can see which methods are in an event at any one time?

## Simplified Example:

**Game manager**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public delegate void ClickAction();
    public static event ClickAction OnClicked;

    void someMethod()
    {
        if(whatever = true && OnClicked != null)
        {
            //this is the event delegate:
            OnClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

**gameObject script** 
*(one of several scripts that can add methods to an `event` )*

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TeleportScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        EventManager.OnClicked += Teleport;
    }

    void SomeOtherMethod(){
        EventManager.OnClicked += Horses; 
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        EventManager.OnClicked -= Teleport;
        EventManager.OnClicked -= Horses;
    }


    void Teleport()
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.y = Random.Range(1.0f, 3.0f);
        transform.position = pos;
    }

    void Horses(){
         instantiate(horses, new Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

*etc. etc.,*

I have used `Debug.Log(OnClicked.Method);` but this only returns one of multiple methods associated with an event.

So my issue is, that for debugging and general error resolution, how can I find out which method(s) are in the `OnClicked()` event delegate without/before running this delegate?

For example:

```
Debug.Log(OnClicked(listMethods));
```

> //Output to log: 
>   void Teleport(); 
>   void Horses();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the InvocationList of the event. Here is a brief code example :

```
 public delegate void Test();
 System.Delegate[] invokeList;
 public static event Test OnTest;

  OnTest += TestMethod1;
  OnTest += TestMethod2;
  invokeList = OnTest.GetInvocationList();
  foreach(System.Delegate d in invokeList)
  {
    Debug.Log(d.Method);
  }
```

Comment: That's fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As a side note, how did you discover this? I was looking all over for this type of solution but wasn't finding anything tha fitted the bill. Altough I was also unaware of `GetInvocationList`

Comment: Well I just created the event and used intellisense to scroll trough all the available properties and methods and GetInvocationList seemed to do what you want from its name alone. After that i was just a matter of writing this small test to be sure and voila.

Comment: oh ffs, I had looked through the invoke list expecting to find something akin to this but I'd clearly missed that function,... now I feel stupid `:-(` hah.